# Widget takes full screen with set size parameters

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am sorry for a newbie question, but I totally can't get the gist of how the following works.

What I'd like to do - I want to create a custom widget, say `CustomPopUp`, and open this PopUp widget when clicking a button.

What's the problem - when I specify the size parameters & constraints for that PopUp widget and try `Navigator.push` it OR call it using `showDialog`, it takes the entire screen, ignoring the sizing and `opaque: false` parameter (in the first case).

Please, find an example below (to simplify, the example is with `showDialog` option only):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text("PushMe"),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => CustomPopUp()
            );
          },
        )

        ),
      );
  }
}

class CustomPopUp extends StatelessWidget { //the custom popup widget 

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: 600, //sizings are just for example
        maxWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 400,
        minWidth: 200),
      height: 600,
      width: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid)
      ),
      child:
      Text("Test")

    );

  }
}
```

Result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgc6d.png)

So, what did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with SizeBox widget if you have fix size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your custom popup with an invisible Dialog:

```dart
      body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("PushMe"),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => Dialog(child: CustomPopUp(), backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,)
              );
            },
          )
      ),
```

now you don't even need the `BoxConstraints`.

a few tips:

1. use the `ConstrainedBox` widget instead of `Container` for constraints
2. use `SizedBox` instead of `Container` for setting height and width.

`Container` will try to match it parent's size by default.

Comment: Thanks! Dialog works.

Another small question regarding your tips: did you mean that it's better to use for example `SizedBox`, and then put `Container` as its child? (and if so, why?) Or just replacing it? The reason for `Container` here was that there is a possibility to use decoration. 

Thanks again!

Comment: ```Container``` is like ```div``` in HTML. it does nothing on it's own until you configure it. ```Container``` is good for making circles, coloring backgrounds and making simple shapes with borders and not very reliable for sizing elements. @Tolya2k

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
/*
Develop by BBesttech  (pvnakum) 17 sep 2019
*/

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text("PushMe"),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                  builder:(_) =>
//                  AlertDialog(context),
                      _buildAboutDialog(context),
              );
            },

          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
// Alert dialog content widget
Widget _buildAboutDialog (BuildContext context){
  return new AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Titel Name'),
    content: new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildAboutText(),
      ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(onPressed: (){
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }, child: Text('OK !'))
    ],


  );
}
Widget _buildAboutText(){
  return new RichText(
      text: new TextSpan(
        text: "Please Type your decription here",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)
      ),
  );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

One thing - I wanted to create a "custom" popup, so that's why `AlertDialog` doesn't work for me.